# Show product price on fly to user before add to cart in prestashop

Tags: prestashop

My motive is to create a module that allow user to enter height and width of product and then automatically price calculated per sq metre and then allow user to add to cart.
For example user 1 select 5 m width and 6 m length and price per sq metre=10 then product price is 5*6*10=300 and then user add to cart. In parrallely on other system user 2 select width 5 and length 2 then he see price 5*2*10=100 and he also allow to add to cart.
Please help me how to manage this on fly price

Answer (score 0):

You should enable two input(type=number) in product page:

```
<input type="number" name="width" id="width" size="6" class="userinput">
<input type="number" name="height" id="height" size="6" class="userinput">
```

Then with jquery calculate the area and assign it to qty value:

```
var area = $("#width).val() * $("#height).val();
$('#qty').val(area);
```

And send the "qty" value to "cart.php":

```
<form method="post" action="{$base_dir}cart.php">
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="{$static_token}" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="id_product" value="{$id_product}" id="id_product" />
<input type="hidden" name="add" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="qty" id="qty" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="buy" name="submit" id="submitbutton">
</form>
```